# Simple Android JSON Parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

*Hello, I am a newbie to android development*

- **I am trying to understand how to parse JSON in android activity**
- **I am not using anything such as PHP etc**
- **I am using NODEJS on server in AWS to generate JSON**

I have a JSON ::
`{"1":"Hello","2":"World"`}

**This JSON is coming from an AWS server i have hosted my application**

- How to parse the JSON data for above JSON ?
- How to populate to an android activity ?

PS:: Any links that would help me understand this concept would also be helpful

Thanks,

Comment: Please refer to the android documentation, it has a detailed example. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Answer (score 1):

In the most basic form, you can parse JSON by simply creating a JSON object and passing the string representation of the JSON object to the constructor, like so...

`JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject("{\"1\":\"Hello\",\"2\":\"World\"}");`

Read the docs on this class for more info on how to extract data from objects and etc... https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

A more abstract way of parsing can be done via the GSON library. In a nutshell, GSON has the ability to take your JSON response and parse it into a Java object for you so that you don't have to do it yourself.

Admittedly using GSON can save a good amount of time from writing code to parse yourself, however, I would probably rather go the `JSONObject` route if you're new to this.